# Complex animations on android

Tags: android, android-animation

im trying to make some animations and i feel really lost.

I have a screen with 3 buttons, when you click one i want to do a TranslateAnimation to move it to top and 3 more buttons appears behind, but im having trouble to make the animations.

I explain more with some pictures.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

So, that initial image and final image, on button 1 click i want to translate it above of button 1-1 and button 1-1 1-2 and 1-3 have to slide form right.

Most animations i´ve used before was sliding elements from out of screen, how can i slide it from that position to the new position?

And how can i do it without buttons 1-1 1-2 1-3 on screen, im using relativeLayout so button 1 is above button 2 and it have to change to above button 1-1 but button 1-1 its not created yet.

Im really lost, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can try with android:animateLayoutChanges="true" and setLayoutPrameter, and addRule in RelativeLayout.LayoutParameter

Comment: im not using xml, how can i use it programatically?

Comment: I tried using animateLayoutChanges and its not doing nothing on my 2.3 phone

Comment: this guy says api 11 http://blog.xamarin.com/android-tricks-eye-candy-using-layout-animations/

Comment: yes correct api level 11 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#setLayoutTransition(android.animation.LayoutTransition)